# Only allow download from specific sites in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, restrictions, blacklist, whitelist

Some of my co-workers in the company that I am working for are downloading torrents and music online; my boss is blaming me for the slow internet connection. We are using Chrome as our only browser and are downloading files from a few sites only. What solution (preferably free) would enable me to allow downloads from white-listed sites only?

Comment: You should use a firewall to control outbound access so that direct access from PCs is blocked, and a proxy server to mediate web access to the internet that has URL filtering.  How to go about implementing and managing this is something best left to a company that deals with this type of thing.  Do you have an IT services provider?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be [Qustodio](https://www.qustodio.com/en/business/) web filtering software.  I use the family version and I've been happy with it.